# C# Class Factories

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a class called Foo that has a function that looks like the following

```
List<Bar> LoadData();
```

Both Foo and Bar are in a library that I want to reuse in other projects. Now I am working on a new project and I want to subclass Bar. Let's call it NewBar.

What is a simple and flexible way to get Foo.LoadData to return a list of NewBar? I think that a factory is needed or perhaps just a delegate function. Can anyone provide an example?

Thanks, Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here. Since you are using `List<Bar>` this would not work if you return `List<Baz>` since `List<>` does not do **covariance**.

My suggestion is to redesign it to return `IEnumerable<Bar>` and make it `virtual` so that in the new project create a `SubFoo` and you can return `IEnumerable<Baz>`.

---

### UPDATE

OK, according to the new information you provided (**you use it for populating list from XML**), I would create a `virtual protected CreateBar()` which creates a new bar object and is called by LoadData() to create new `Bar` in the loop. In the `SubFoo` I override and return `Baz` instead. In the `SubFoo` I will call `base.LoadData()` and populate the `Baz` list and then add the logic to populate new properties of `Baz` which are not in `Bar`.

### Or perhaps

just use XML Serilization and I get all of that for free!

Comment: The function LoadData does some processing on the Bar objects after creating them and putting them in the list. How would SubFoo call LoadData on it's parent, Foo, and return List<Baz>?

Comment: It is not returning `List<Baz>`, it is returning `IEnumerable<Bar>`. I corrected it. Without giving more information on what the function actually does, none of answers would make a lot of sense. You need to share that information.

Comment: That was a typo. What would the contents of IEnumerable<Baz> SubFoo.LoadData() look like?

Comment: The function parses an XML file, creates Bar objects, sets the properties on the Bar objects and then adds them to the list.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe even simplier, depends on what you need, but generic constraints may suffice if Bar is constructed with parameterless constructor:

```
public List<TBar> LoadData<TBar>()
    where TBar : Bar, new()
{
    // return a list populated with `new TBar()`;
}
```

Usage:

```
var newBars = Foo.LoadData<NewBar>();
```

Comment: This is probably not an acceptable approach, because generally classes which require factories have a more complex creation requirement than a public parameterless constructor.  In addition, using setters to initialize a class is a poor design by comparison to constructor injection, because objects can be created with invalid state and there is no way to validate them.  I did not down vote you, because I think the recommended use of generics for a strongly typed result is useful, however, overall the solution you suggested is flawed.

Comment: I cannot see any point in this. If I can use any subclass and pass it, factory method **would not use the type information I have passed to it other than constructing it**. In this case, what would such a subclass provide over `Bar`?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to have an interface implemented by Bar and NewBar, and have your function return `List<IBar>` instead.

It's that or return `object` and cast galore.

Comment: I didn't mention it in my original question because I didn't think it was relevant, but maybe it is. Bar is a child of a simpler class that is also in the library, so I'm not sure I can use an interface.

Answer (score 1):

Make `LoadData()` virtual.  Then override it in a derived factory.

If the derived factory method would still return a list of `Bar`, but you could specify in the method implementation that all of the `Bar` instances are actually `NewBar`.  This could be altered by using a generic method like in Snowbear's example.

Comment: This will not work since `List<T>` does not do **covariance**.

Comment: It can return `IEnumerable<T>` and then allow the caller to use `.ToList()` if they want.

Comment: @Aliostad, if you read the answer you'd see that I set it would return a `List<Bar>`, but the implementation would have to specify that each instance was a `NewBar`.  To get a `List<NewBar>` you could just do `Cast<NewBar>().ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

It's time you learn about covariance and contravariance. It's not a small thing to learn. Basically I'd suggest creating an IBar interfarce, it'll make your life much easier.

Read about the concepts [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), but you should keep looking for other examples too.

Answer (score 0):

Having read the answers (thanks!) I came up with the following. Why is this not a good idea?

```
public interface IBarFactory
{
    Bar Create();
}
```

Then change LoadData to:

```
List<Bar> LoadData(IBarFactory Factory)
{
    List<Bar> MyList = new List<Bar>();

    if (Factory == null)
    {
        MyList.Add(new Bar());
    }
    else
    {
        MyList.Add(Factory.Create());
    }

    // etc, etc
}
```

Then I just need to create the following:

```
public class BazFactory : IBarFactory
{
    Bar Create() { return new Baz() };
}
```

Finally call it:

```
MyList = LoadData(BazFactory);
```